# React remove blur onClick

Tags: reactjs

I have a search box with an autocomplete wrapped around it using antd components and when the input is populated and you click the search button, the dropdown still shows. It doesnt hide itself. Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lookup-patterns-uncertain-category-antd4112-forked-gkgf0) to the codesandbox. These are the steps to reproduce:

1. Type in any text in the input.
2. click outside of the area on the black page to unfocus it
3. Click the search button

The dropdown shouldnt show again.